# output voltage of boost converter

Tags: voltage, frequency, boost, converter, code

I built a boost converter and I can't see on the oscilloscope the 12V in the output and the real frequency that I defined (70kHz.)

What should I do?

This is my circuit, and below that is what I see in the oscilloscope:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I presume you have either very low load, or poorly done feedback for your boost converter, if a single boost cycle sends your output voltage far higher than set point you can end up like this

Comment: when I measure in the voltmeter i can see12v  ,and in the simulation I see the 12V

Comment: Ok, then are you sure your probe is not set to X1 and the scope is expecting X10? that would lead to it showing 10x the voltage?

Comment: Why would you expect to see the drive frequency in the output?

Comment: I saw on the gate of the transistor the 70khz and the priod time , its working but If I want to see the output voltage I get this (in the picture)

Comment: I dont know I should see the frequency that I defined in the code 70khz and the dc voltage 12V

Comment: There is no feedback.  That is to say,  nothing that would regulate the output voltage to 12 volts.  Any difference in component values between the simulator and the real circuit can lead to differences between the simulator and your real circuit.

Comment: Yes, the 70kHz must be visible at the gate of the FET.

Comment: Please check the probe multiplier as Reroute suggested.

Comment: how I cheack that?

Comment: If using a scope probe there is usually a slide switch on it near the middle with "X1" and "X10", make sure its pushed towards "X10", otherwise in your scope make sure its set up to use an "X1" probe

Comment: this is my scope i dont have slide switch

Comment: [TDS1001 manual.](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/equipment/TEKtds1002.pdf)  Press the "Ch 1" button.  The probe setting is described on page 112 of the manual.

Comment: The probe setting in the menu must match the probe (and its setting) that you are using.  If your probe is set to 1X and the menu is set to 10X, then you will get values that are 10 times to high.  1V in your circuit would be displayed as 10V.

Comment: Correction.  "Ch 2 Menu" since your picture shows you are using channel 2.

Comment: Your scope picture shows 124 volts - clearly that is too much (duty cycle incorrect) but it does look like it is operational.